# Is it worth dropping stale columns on a large data set?

Tags: django, postgresql

I have a relatively large data set in a table with about 60 columns, of which about 20 have gone stale.  I've found a few posts on dropping multiple columns and the performance of `DROP COLUMN`, but nothing on whether or not dropping a bunch of columns would result in a noticeable performance increase.

Any insight as to whether or not something like this could a perceptible impact?

Answer (score 1):

Dropping one or more columns can be done in a single statement and is very fast. All it needs is a short `ACCESS EXCLUSIVE` lock on the table, so long running queries would block it.

The table is not rewritten during this operation, and it will not shrink. Subsequent rewrites (with `VACUUM (FULL)` or similar) will get rid of the column data.